# How to combine the command to select a device and ping the device using cmd prompt and not GenyShell

Tags: command, command-prompt, ping, genymotion

Using GenyShell command window, i'm able to select a device and ping the particular device.

```
Genymotion Shell > devices list

|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| Several Genymotion virtual devices are running.               |
| Please, select a device manually with command: devices select |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|

Available devices:

 Id | Select |    Status     |   Type   |   IP Address    |      Name
----+--------+---------------+----------+-----------------+---------------
  0 |        |            On |  virtual |  192.168.56.101 | Android Emulator
  1 |        |            On |  virtual |  192.168.56.102 | Samsung-6.0.0-API23
Genymotion Shell > devices select 0
Selecting device id 0
Genymotion device selected: Android Emulator
Genymotion Shell > devices ping
Pong received
```

Same commands when i try to perform in the command prompt window, i'm getting error.

```
C:\Users\Ramkumar>genyshell -c "devices list"
Logging activities to file: C:/Users/Ramkumar/AppData/Local/Genymobile/genymotion-shell.log
Connection mode: local host

Welcome to Genymotion Shell

Available devices:

 Id | Select |    Status     |   Type   |   IP Address    |      Name
----+--------+---------------+----------+-----------------+---------------
  0 |        |            On |  virtual |  192.168.56.101 | Android Emulator
  1 |        |            On |  virtual |  192.168.56.102 | Samsung-6.0.0-API23

C:\Users\Ramkumar>genyshell -c "devices select 0"
Logging activities to file: C:/Users/Ramkumar/AppData/Local/Genymobile/genymotion-shell.log
Connection mode: local host

|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| Several Genymotion virtual devices are running.               |
| Please, select a device manually with command: devices select |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|

Welcome to Genymotion Shell
Selecting device id 0
Genymotion device selected: Android Emulator

C:\Users\Ramkumar>genyshell -c "devices ping"
Logging activities to file: C:/Users/Ramkumar/AppData/Local/Genymobile/genymotion-shell.log
Connection mode: local host

|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| Several Genymotion virtual devices are running.               |
| Please, select a device manually with command: devices select |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|

Welcome to Genymotion Shell
No virtual device selected.
```

Is there any way we can combine this two commands like selecting a device and ping it back. I'm not sure if i'm missing any commands. I want to perform this commands in my code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
/Applications/Genymotion\ Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/genyshell -r 192.168.57.101 -c "gps setlocation 42"
```